# How to merge two lists at a delimited token in python3

Tags: python-3.x, custom-lists

I am a CS major at the University of Alabama, we have a project in our python class and I am stuck...probably for some stupid reason, but I cant seem to find the answer.

here is the link to the project, as it would be a pain to try and explain on here.

http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs150/projects/project1.html

here is my code:

```
import sys
from scanner import scan

def clInput():
    #Gets command line input

    log1 = sys.argv[1]
    log2 = sys.argv[2]
    name = sys.argv[3]

    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print('Incorrect number of arguments, should be 3')
        sys.exit(1)
    return log1,log2,name

def openFiles(log1,log2):
    #Opens sys.argv[1]&[2] for reading

    f1 = open(log1, 'r')
    f2 = open(log2, 'r')
    return f1, f2


def merge(log1,log2):
    #Merges parsed logs into list without '---'

    log1Parse = [[]]
    log2Parse = [[]]
    log1Count = 0
    log2Count = 0
    for i in log1:
        if i != ['---']:
            log1Parse[log1Count].append(i)
        else:
            log1Count += 1
            log1Parse.append([])

    for i in log2:
        if i != ['---']:
            log2Parse[log2Count].append(i)
        else:
            log2Count += 1
            log2Parse.append([])

return(log1Parse[0] + log2Parse[0] + log1Parse[1] + log2Parse[1])


def searchMerge(name,merged):
    #Searches Merged list for sys.argv[3]

    for i in range(len(merged)):
        if (merged[i][1] == name):
            print(merged[i][0],merged[i][1]," ".join(merged[i][2:]))



def main():
    log1,log2,name = clInput()
    f1,f2 = openFiles(log1,log2)

    #Sets the contents of the two scanned files to variables
    tokens1 = scan(f1)
    tokens2 = scan(f2)

    #Call to merge and search
    merged = merge(tokens1,tokens2)
    searchMerge(name,merged)




main()
```

ok. so heres the problem. We are to merge two lists together into a sorted master list, delimited at the ---'s

my two log files match the ones posted on the website i linked to above. This code works, however if there are more than two instances of the ---'s in each list, it will not jump to the next list to get the other tokens, and so forth. I have it working for two with the merge function. at the end of that function i return

```
return(log1Parse[0] + log2Parse[0] + log1Parse[1] + log2Parse[1])
```

but this only works for two instances of ---. Is there anyway i can change my return to look at all of the indexes instead of having to manually put in [0],[1],[2], etc.? I need it to delimit and merge for an arbitrary amount. Please help!!

p.s. disregard the noobness...im a novice, we all gotta start somewhere

p.p.s. - the from scanner import scan is a scanner i wrote to take in all of the tokens in a given list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**so.py:**

```
import sys

def main():
    # check and load command line arguments
    # your code
    if len(sys.argv) != 4:
        print('Incorrect number of arguments, should be 3')
        sys.exit(1)

    # open files using file io
    # your code
    f1 = open(log1, 'r')
    f2 = open(log2, 'r')

    # list comprehension to process and filter log files
    l1 = [ x.strip().split(" ",2) for x in f1.readlines() if x.strip() != "---" ]
    l2 = [ x.strip().split(" ",2) for x in f2.readlines() if x.strip() != "---" ]

    f1.close()
    f2.close()

    sorted_merged_lists = sorted(l1 + l2)

    results = [ x for x in sorted_merged_lists if x[1] == name ]

    for result in results:
        print result

main()
```

**CLI:**

```
$ python so.py log1.txt log2.txt Matt
['12:06:12', 'Matt', 'Logged In']
['13:30:07', 'Matt', 'Opened Terminal']
['15:02:00', 'Matt', 'Opened Evolution']
['15:31:16', 'Matt', 'Logged Out']
```

**docs:**

> http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions
>   http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip
>   http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split
>   http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply, however I need to have everything outputted as:
   12:06:12 Matt Logged In
   13:30:07 Matt Opened Terminal
   15:02:00 Matt Opened Evolution
   15:31:16 Matt Logged Out

Comment: I was going to go back and redact the code but take a look at the docs i linked at the bottom. joining the list back together with spaces: `print " ".join(result)` in the for loop should get you the formatting you are looking for